# Looking for a tpl.php cheat

Tags: theming

I am wanting to develop some VERY simple tpl.php files. I would like to just open a WYSIWYG and edit them quickly, outputting the html that I can then copy-n-paste into the specific tpl.php files for my custom theme.

I know that I could do this in Dreamweaver or similar application.

I'm looking for a free service, online app, etc. I'm hoping that I am NOT the only person that would like to do this and someone else has figured out a quick way to do this.

I would rather avoid building this non-visually, strictly in code. It would be nice to move some objects around on a screen, maybe adjust some CSS properties visually, and then, when I am done -> Dump to code. Copy-n-paste. Modify for Drupal variables. Go.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Well, you can use Dreamweaver to develop for Drupal all right. There are free tools and configuration sets to make it easier, easy to find.

Comment: Since the question is asking for online resources, I would say it is off-topic as per [FAQ].

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a "Drupal template GUI" - such a thing doesn't exist unfortunately. You might be able to fudge a Dreamweaver extension together (although Dreamweaver is evil, and must be stopped before it's too late). Other than that you're at the mercy of xyz HTML GUI that can be customised to think like Drupal. Such a thing would be a large technical challenge to even conceive, let alone build, so I think you're out of luck here

Comment: So there isn't a simple html gui editor?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I am not looking for online resources... I am looking for anything that would make simple tpl.php file editing easier, faster and less code-based. I'm also confused as heck as to why I lost reputation on this question?! I wasn't rude, I was direct and (I thought) clear in my question. I am so confused...

Comment: Sure, there are dozens of HTML GUIs out there, but in my experience every last one of them is terrible (just look at the crappy, un-semantic, mess of code that Dreamweaver et al. spits out). I thought you were asking for one with Drupal integration though? If you're just looking for recommendations for a generic HTML GUI then Stack Exchange isn't really the place to ask, recommendation questions go against the Q&A paradigm. I haven't downvoted, but at a guess that's why it's negatively scored at the moment

Comment: I was referring to your, "I'm looking for a free service, online app, etc." which for me are online resources. I didn't down-vote either, but as pointed out from @Clive, the question could be seen as recommendation question, and down-voted for that reason. Down-votes are not a way to say the user has been rude.

Comment: @Clive & kiamlaluno
Thank you both. Yeah, I was hoping there was something that I could plug in basic placeholder variables, tweak some HTML/CSS layout (very much like W3Schools little IDE / Layout trainer javascript app) and then dump the resulting code to the clipboard. Oh well... and thanks for the downvoting heads up. I am still learning my way around stackexchange... I just hate getting penalized while in Newb mode... oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Learning to design something by code might be a bit daunting at first, however it is possible to view a themes' regions in Drupal which makes life much easier when you know what the dimensions are (and can test responsive design if you resize your window or use a bookmarklet of some javascript or better yet use the Web Developer extensions that all good browsers have).

Drupal Gardens explains a bit about Regions, I believe they also have a decent Theme Builder:
http://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/themebuilder/regions
http://www.drupalgardens.com/themebuilder

Anyway, I came across Light Table a while back which can help when you're writing some JavaScript for a HTML5 Canvas animation, as the IDE allows you to view the changes almost instantly (after you press the shortcut to run the code):
http://www.lighttable.com/

However I've not used it with a Drupal site, so I'm not sure if it'd work well.

There were others I've seen posts about recently such as TopStyle:
http://topstyle4.com/

Though I have no experience with it as I prefer Sublime Text and Vim.

Comment: It isn't that designing by code is daunting, it's that with a visual IDE I believe I could develop more quickly. I am really just wanting to edit nodes for a custom content type. The custom content type has several sub-types that each need specialized HTML layout for the presentation I am wanting to do. So if I could just open a mini window, create a generic layout for the content type, then edit it for each sub-type, and with each edit if I could just hit save and dump to code... then I could just massage Drupal variables into those edits and voila! tpl!